# Is it possible to customise react-native-media-controls styling?

Tags: react-native

I have a video component that uses react-native-video with react-native-media-controls, I want to be able to customise the Styling of the controls. Is this possible to do on react-native-media-controls?

```
    <MediaControls
      duration={this.state.duration}
      isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
      mainColor="orange"
      onFullScreen={this.onFullScreen}
      onPaused={this.onPaused}
      onReplay={this.onReplay}
      onSeek={this.onSeek}
      playerState={this.state.playerState}
      progress={this.state.currentTime}
      toolbar={this.renderToolbar()}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the @react-native-media-controls library. The author just made the "mainColor" style is customizable. Actually it could be customizable if you really need an emergency issue I can fork it and make it customizable, however, this PR takes time to merge. However, you can install it with my fork. Do you need it?

### **UPDATED:**

I've updated the library and opened a PR.

https://github.com/charliesbot/react-native-media-controls/pull/17

If someone needs to use it with updated version, it is available on my repo until this PR will be merged.

Comment: Actually @Kuray -FreakyCoder- Please create the fork for me, I do need it. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Cya, I'm going to make it customizable ASAP.

Comment: Thanks, will be waiting for your link

Comment: Hello again @Cya,
I've updated the library completely. 
https://github.com/charliesbot/react-native-media-controls/pull/17

You can use it from my repo until this PR will be merged :) I hope that helps to you.

Comment: @ Kuray -FreakyCoder- Thanks so much, I am integrating in now.